# Python Algorithm: search in a list which difference is equal to k

Tags: python, algorithm

```
number = [5,1,5,3,4]
k = 2
```

return the count which the difference is equal to k

```
cnt = 0
for i in nums:
   for j in nums:
       if i != j:
            if i-j == k:
                cnt += 1
return cnt
```

You can solve by O(N^2)
Can it be done in a faster way in terms of complexity?

it should return 3 because there are three cases which the difference is equal 2

```
5-3=2, 5-3=2, 3-1=2
```

Comment: What if you sort the list?

Comment: @AndréLaszlo okay so you sort the list and then?

Comment: Then you could start at the beginning of the list and add a match only if `number[i]+2 in (number[i+1], number[i+2])` or something along those lines.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo i tried that but the problem is that when you after you find the match, what number to use is the tricky part. you would still have to go back and loop through, i think

Comment: for example, 5, 5, 4, 3, 1. after you find that 5-3 is 2, how would you go back to the second 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple `O(n * log(n))` solution with constant memory usage:

1. Sort the list : `O(n * log(n))`
2. For each element `k` in the sorted list, search for `k + 2` in the list using *binary search*: `<count of elements which is n> * O(log(n))`

Hence overall complexity is `O(n * log(n))`.

Note that step `2` above can be made into a `O(n)` complexity using two pointers.

Comment: yes this is the correct approach, i believe. thank you

Comment: It's a good solution, but hashing is still faster. Sorting is better though if you prefer to save memory instead of time.

Comment: @VadimPushtaev as mentioned earlier: Unless there is infinite memory, hash lookup or any lookup cannot be O(1) for _all sizes_ of the hash set. Even if there was infinite memory, just computation of the mapping to the location would start to tend towards O(log(n)).

Comment: *shrug* it's still faster than sorting, even complexity-wise. But both solutions are ok for some situations.

Answer (score 3):

The simple O(n) solution is to create an index using hashtable (`set` in python work perfectly) and look for a pair for each element in the list.

But since we care for the number of identical items, we should use `dict` or `Counter` to track the number of them.

```
from collections import Counter

number = [5,1,5,3,4]
k = 2

index = Counter(number)

for x in number:
  if x + k in index:
    for _ in range(0, index[x + k]):
      print (x, x + k)
```

Comment: This is O(N) *on average*, not worst case.

Comment: No, it's aways O(N). Mind that O(2N) == O(N).

Comment: i suppose you mean that hashtable lookup O(1). set has a lookup of O(1)?

Comment: @ealeon [Yes](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt).

Comment: Hash lookup **cannot** be worst case O(1). It's only either amortized O(1) or average case O(1). If `set` was implemented as a tree it would be O(log n) and this would become O(n log n) like the sorting solution.

Comment: how does this algo account for that fact that there are two 5's? 3+2 check would only gives the count of 1, not 2

Comment: Unless there is infinite memory, hash lookup or any lookup cannot be O(1) for _all sizes_ of the hash set. Even if there was infinite memory, just computation of the mapping to the location would start to tend towards O(log(n)),

Comment: @VadimPushtaev but if thats the case.. it will still return 2 if there is only one 5???

Comment: @ealeon fixed. And it's still faster than sorting :).

Comment: @user1952500 what you say does not make any sense. Hash is `O(1)` on average. Also take a look at what `n` are you talking about, because you are confusing `n` the length of an element you are trying to hash and `n` the number of data elements.

Comment: @SalvadorDali could you tell me how you would hash a stream of 20 billion integers with constant time lookups ? The amount of memory needed to store it would be 80GB in a machine where an int takes 4 bytes.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, you are right about the formula computation part. It'll tend towards log(log(n)).

Comment: @SalvadorDali, look at the `Key Statistics` of the wiki entry on Hash Tables(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). The complexity is `O(n/k)` where `k` is the number of buckets. It says: As the load factor grows larger, the hash table becomes slower, and it may even fail to work (depending on the method used). The expected constant time property of a hash table assumes that the load factor is kept below some bound. For a fixed number of buckets, the time for a lookup grows with the number of entries and therefore the desired constant time is not achieved.

Comment: @user1952500 in a similar way you can tell that hash is `O(n)` if you have only one bucket. The thing is that for a majority of applications you have enough buckets to treat hash as O(1). Otherwise you are doing it wrong. Just curious how often were you in a situation that you needed to deal with 20 bln integers? And even for this example it is not hard to span 160GB ram instance to be able to have O(n) time algorithm.

Comment: @SalvadorDali, you're missing the point. It's not an arithmetic gimmick but the fact that there is a constant factor involved. Libraries in programming languages such as Java8 revert to using a balanced binary tree for the bucket after a particular threshold is reached. So it won't be as bad as O(n) but it won't be O(1) either, if you use some standard implementation of HashMap. (I remember the case to be the same many years ago in C++ STL but can't look up now).

Comment: It looks like this discussion is going nowhere. One more time will try to tell that search in hash is O(1) with a very high probability. If you want, write a program which uses BBT to find something in it and the same with hash and compare the results.

Comment: I mentioned the BBT within a bucket, not on the whole hash.

Yes, it looks like this argument will not go anywhere, as this argument uses experience over small numbers of elements as the argument rather than algorithmic analysis over large number of elements or a general case. The simplistic case can use a _perfect hash function_ while the generic case cannot. It will be useful to read the relevant chapters on Knuth's TAoCP vol 3 for more clarity.

Answer (score 1):

This uses a generator.  It is still O(N^2), but should be twice as fast because you only check one side of the pair.  For example, if the the numbers are [3, 1, 4], you only check (3-1), (3-4) and (1-4) instead of (3-1), (3-4), (1-3), (1-4), (4-3), (4-1).

```
>>> sum(1 if abs(x - y) == k else 0 
        for n, x in enumerate(number) 
        for y in number[(n + 1):])
3
```

**Update**

Counter can be used to reduce the size of the list.  If for some value `m` in the list of numbers there exists a number `n` such that `m` + `k` = `n`, then the total count is increased by the product of the count of each.  For example, for numbers = [1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3] and k = 2, Counter would be {1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 3} and there would be six pairs: 2 x 3 => (1, 3) six times.  One can use `get` to retrieve the value of `m` + `k` (defaulting to zero if it does not exist).

I believe this is O(n), as time scales linearly with the length of numbers (although the time increases slightly as the range is increased).

```
from collections import Counter
import numpy as np
```

**Timings**

*Old method*

```
%%timeit np.random.seed(0); numbers = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10000)
sum(1 if abs(x - y) == k else 0 
            for n, x in enumerate(numbers) 
            for y in numbers[(n + 1):])
1 loops, best of 3: 17 s per loop
```

*New method*

```
%%timeit np.random.seed(0); numbers = np.random.randint(1, 100, 10000)  
k = 10
count = 0
c = Counter(numbers)
for key in c:
    count += c[key] * c.get(key + k, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.83 ms per loop

# numbers are 100x larger.
%%timeit np.random.seed(0); numbers = np.random.randint(1, 100, 1000000)  
k = 10
count = 0
c = Counter(numbers)
for key in c:
    count += c[key] * c.get(key + k, 0)
100 loops, best of 3: 380 ms per loop
```

Comment: This is still O(N^2)

Comment: Agreed, but the OP asked if it can be done faster.  This method should be 2x faster.

Comment: I meant to say complexity wise :P

Comment: but i def thought of this approach as well. some sort of caching because there are calculations which are overlapped. though complexity wise it's still the same

Answer (score 1):

You could use itertools. Also you could use generator which is more efficient.

```
import itertools

number = [5,1,5,3,4]
k = 2

for item in itertools.combinations(number,2):
   if abs(item[0] - item[1]) == k :
     print item
```

(Or)

the same code in one line(below):

```
print [item for item in itertools.combinations(number,2) if abs(item[0] - item[1]) == k ]
```

Comment: It's still O(n^2), why do you think it's any faster?